# Casting boolean to Boolean in java

Tags: java, boolean, casting

i have a code as

```
public class BooleanTest {
    public BooleanTest() {
        super();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
      BooleanTest bt = new BooleanTest();
      bt.doProcess();

    }

    private boolean method() {
        return false;
    }

    private void doProcess() {
      Boolean obj = (Boolean)method();
      System.out.println(obj.booleanValue());
    }
}
```

the question is can line  `System.out.println(obj.booleanValue());` throw `NullPointerException` in any situation?

Comment: Every time I see it I wonder why people write no args constructors and explicitly call super().

Comment: Because someone might add another constructor and you want to make sure the noarags constructor is always present. Because it's logically more explicit. Though I must admit in an illustrative code snippet it's not very useful.

Comment: There's also no need to call super().

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, when you box a primitive value into its equivalent wrapper type, the result is never null.

Comment: That's because a primitive type can **never** be null.

Answer (score 8):

**No**,

**Reason:** primitive never hold null so converting them to Wrapper will **never** lead to NPE,

And also **no need to caste** it will [autobox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

Comment: It's not really anything to do with default values. It's to do with the fact that primitive types are value types - the value of an `int` variable is the integer itself, not a reference... so how could it ever be `null`?

Comment: @Jon, I mentioned about default value just to make OP understand that in any case primitive won't hold NULL

Comment: life.java: To me, that confuses things more than making them clearer. The difference between value types and reference types has very little to do with default values.

Comment: @Jon I too realized that after reading your comment, Updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

It will never throw a NPE and also if you are using java >= 1.5, you don't need to cast it. It is called autoboxing which is introduced from JDK 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be pedantic, you might have set System.out to be null, then that line will generate an NPE.
But that would be odd.